# Send email with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I setup an email verification after a user has signed up, but when user receives email, it just says "info" in the FROM column in GMAIL. Is there a way I can change it to say something else like "Example.com" or " Email Verification"? I just want the user to see whom the email is from before opening it.

Here's how it's defined in config/constants.php - using CakePHP

```
if(!defined('EMAIL_FROM')) {

define('EMAIL_FROM', 'info@example.com');

}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding it in front of the email adress would work :

```
if(!defined('EMAIL_FROM')) {    
  define('EMAIL_FROM', 'Email Verification <info@example.com>');    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To define the from field you need to set it after initiating the CakeEmail object as shown in the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
$email->to('you@example.com');
$email->subject('About');
$email->send('My message');
```

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the email address you can use the Configure class to store the value, or a constant as the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this help you

$this->Email->from = Configure::read('FROM_EMAIL');